# Добавить класс к блоку внутри блока

Tags: jquery

Как при наведении мышки на блок добавить класс в блоку, который находится внутри, но не является дочерним (обернут в еще один блок) ?

```
<li class="price">
<div class="price-image-wrapper">
    <img src="images/img_6.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="price-image-inner-block">
        <input name="" type="button" class="price-button-1 btn-1" value="Отправить">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="price-text-wrapper">
    <p class="price-text-1">text</p>
    <p class="price-text-2">1010/1012</p>
</div>
</li>
```

При наведении мышки на `.price` нужно добавить класс .visible к блоку `.price-image-inner-block`.

Скрипт

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('.price').hover(function(){ 
            $(this).children('.price-image-wrapper').children('.price-image-inner-block').toggleClass('visible');
            });

    });
```

работает, но в консоли Хрома выдается предупреждение
`event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

пробуй так. кстати это предупреждение я тоже видел. Это, мне кажется, на саму библиотеку нужно грешить, так как ошибка возникает в самом jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.price').hover(
            function(){ 
                $(this).find('.price-image-inner-block').toggleClass('visible');
            }
        );
});
```

Comment: Ага, спасибо, работает!    
Предупреждение да, ругается на саму библиотеку, но почему-то когдо я этот скрипт убираю, оно пропадает (при этом на странице другие скрипты есть), а если скрипт добавляю, оно снова появляется.

Comment: Похоже, это баг браузера  
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14282  
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14320